# Selenium can't swrite something on the search bar

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on scraping a job website using Selenium with C#. As I run the application,the chromewebdriver opens, as soon as it opens a model pops up on the website and then, the progam closes it, however my program stops it execution soon after. The intention is to close this modal -> Type something on the search bar and press "Enter". However, I can't type something on the search bar, because it gives the error:
`Timed out after 20 seconds`. What should I to solve it?[image]

```js
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace JobWebScraper
{
    public class AutomationWeb
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;

        public AutomationWeb() 
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(); //vai abrir o navegador do Chrome
        }

        public void TestWeb()
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://portal.gupy.io/?int_ref=navbar-candidatos");

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"radix-0\"]/div[2]/button")).Click();

            // Use an explicit wait for the search input field to be clickable and then send keys
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));


            // Wait for the search input field to be clickable and then send keys
            IWebElement searchInput = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"react-aria-9\"]")));

            // Send keys directly after the element is clickable
            searchInput.SendKeys("desenvolvedor");
            searchInput.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: you can try/catch the wait to allow things to continue, but it's telling you that it has timed out trying to find a clickable element using that XPATH.  The site's also throwing a lot of errors all on it's own there... (it's trying to load scripts that the server is not allowing through csp directive, which may be leading to the later unauthorized request.)

Comment: This line is a problem 

IWebElement searchInput = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"react-aria-9\"]")));

provide DOM code and tell us what element you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an issue, because you rely on wrong input.

For me there are 2 search inputs are present in DOM.
First one is not visible (probably it is rendered on mobile view), and second one is visible and interactable.

So, you should filter inputs with locators `[name=searchTerm]` by visibility and interact with first found element.

```
// previous code
var searchInputs = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("[name=searchTerm]")));
var visibleInput = searchInputs.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Displayed);

visibleInput?.SendKeys("desenvolvedor");
visibleInput?.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);
```

Comment: it does not work

Comment: @olamundo97 no way it doesn't work. Here is proof with your code + my code that it works as expected: https://monosnap.com/file/xIv2x5cR4cDS2EzAbUi8KbGj1MWv6y
(I replaced Expected conditions to ExplicitWait as far as I have newest version of Selenium installed, but that shouldn't be the reason that Expected Conditions don't work).

Comment: thanks, I realized I was doing something wrong